# Create an Excel worksheet based on specific column values

Tags: vba, excel

I am enclosing a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDySv.jpg) with a sample spreadsheet.

What I would like to do is create multiple worksheets using the key column of "Facility", perhaps using a macro.  For example, I would like to create a new worksheet called `Houston` and fill the worksheet with the data specific to that row.  Some of the cells may end up in different locations in the new worksheet.  I need to do a separate worksheet for every value in "Facility".  The original that I am working on has 270 rows (270 facilities).

Does anyone have any idea how to do something like this?  I am new to running and creating macros.  I did create a macro that didn't work right.

Comment: Hi. SO is about helping with problems in your code, so why don't you share the bit of code you tried with us? By looking at the code and with you providing information about what went wrong, we'll be better able to help you.

Comment: Sorry about that, here is the code that I generated creating the simple macro.  Also, I have attached a link to a new image with row and column values......http://imgur.com/z2DtfaD

Sub Macro9()
'
' Macro9 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Schedule").Select
    Range("G4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub

Comment: It is not formatting my code the way that I intended.....

Comment: You can edit your question and post your code there. But as there already is an answer, you can take this as a hint for future questions ;)

Comment: Yes I see that now.  Thanks for the tip!  Working on the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lstRow As ListRow

For Each lstRow In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    wks.Name = lstRow.Range.Cells(, 1).Value
    With wks
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lstRow.Range.Columns.Count)) = lstRow.Range.Value
    End With
Next

Set wks = Nothing
```

Assumptions:

- Worksheet name where data resides is called Sheet1
- Table containing data is a ListObject (e.g., convert your data range into an Excel table)
- ListObject name is Table1

Comment: Where do I put that code?  Again, I am a beginner at these advanced Excel techniques.

Comment: In a code module through your VBE. Do a quick web search on how to insert code in your macro-enabled project. There are tons of guides to show you how.

Comment: OK I got that far.  Now, how do I run the code that I just inserted?

Comment: Place your cursor anywhere within the procedure and hit F5.

Comment: The current problem that I have is that I have no macros saved since I deleted the ones that weren't working. When I try to create a macro, "create" is greyed out.  The only option that I have is to record a macro.